# Did I drink too much eggnog? I see hats double!

Tags: discussion, support, winter-bash, bug-reports

'Tis the season of happy holidays, office parties (maybe not with covid), and some other traditions like hanging mistletoe, drinking eggnog, or earning some Winter Bash hats...

The thing is that, I don't know if I had a little too much eggnog, but I see the Winter Bash hats double. Especially when executing code on StackOverflow: one hat stays static on the page while the other hat accompanies the profile picture. You can see one example on [this answer on StackOverflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/414673/250):

[image: Screenshot of answer from StackOverflow en español]

After clicking on the "Ejecutar" button:

[image: Screenshot of answer from StackOverflow en español, two hats are displayed now]

I would have expected the hat to be an overlay on top of the profile, but it seems it isn't. There are two (one for the avatar picture and another for the profile card?) and one doesn't move as expected... either that or I had one-too-many cups of eggnog. Funny thing is that it seems to fix itself after a few expand/collapses.

Anyway, it seems like a little happy Winter-Bashy bug. It doesn't seem too important and I don't know if it has been reported before (I searched for it, but didn't find it).

---

```html
<h1>Steps to replicate the "bug":</h1>
<ol>
  <li>Click on the "Run code snippet" button</li>
  <li>See Alvaro's hat doubles</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yes, it does. Let me close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: it's quite difficult to see double vertically, even intentionally

Comment: @user400654 I didn't know what. That's quite a fun fact. Is there a medical/biological reason for that?

Comment: +1 for the clever, descriptive text when testing the bug.